# How do you refresh a component's template in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, templates, components

I am completely new to Angular 2 (doing the Tour of Heroes tutorial now) and I created a component that has two-way data binding to an array of objects that are being displayed as a list in the template. I have wired a click event so that when a list item is clicked the object associated with the list item is stored as a property called selectedItem and a sub-component is called that shows the details of the selected item.  Typical master/detail stuff.

However, instead of having the detail displayed on the click event, I want the list of items in the template reloaded with a new list of items.  I have a little service that knows how to get the new list that I want, but I can't figure out how to reload the component or refresh the template so that the new list of items are displayed.

My object array looks like this: (scriptID, scriptName, scriptOrderID, scriptParentID).  Each object in the array has a scriptParentID that is the scriptID of another object in the array.  When I click on a list item, my new list is all the objects where their scriptParentID is the scriptID of the item clicked.

So what I am after is a component that displays a list and then any time an item is clicked in the list, its children appear in the list.

It's just a simple exercise to help learn state management, components, and templates, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<ul class="heroes">
<li *ngFor="let script of scripts" [class.selected]="script === selectedScript" (click)="onSelect(script)">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <span class="badge">{{script.scriptOrderID}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <span>{{script.scriptName}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <span class="badge2">{{script.scriptID}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

`<my-script-detail [script]="selectedScript"></my-script-detail>`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
scripts: Script[];
selectedScript: Script;
title = 'Sandbox';

constructor(private scriptService: ScriptService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getScriptsByParentID(1);
 }

onSelect(script: Script): void{
   this.selectedScript = script;
   this.getScriptsByParentID(script.scriptParentID);
 }

getScriptsByParentID(parentID: number): void {
  this.scriptService.getScriptsByParentID(parentID).then(scripts => this.scripts = scripts);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing script.scriptParentID to getScriptsByParentID method, you should pass the script.scriptID. It's the ID of the clicked element that is a parent.

I don't see the code of your scriptService.getScriptsByParentID method but in case it retrieves all scripts, you have to filter to get only the children.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    scripts: Script[];
    selectedScript: Script;
    title = 'Sandbox';

    constructor(private scriptService: ScriptService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getScriptsByParentID(1);
    }

    onSelect(script: Script): void{
        this.selectedScript = script;
        this.getScriptsByParentID(script.scriptID);
    }

    getScriptsByParentID(parentID: number): void {
        this.scriptService.getScriptsByParentID(parentID).then(scripts => this.scripts = scripts.find(script=> script.scriptParentID === parentID));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I feel stupid.  I was just passing the wrong parameter. Thanks!